# Using PHP & MySQL As Desktop Application

Tags: php, mysql, web, xampp, desktop-application

My company was using a desktop application developed in VB which was old and not fulfilling new requirements.
I developed a local web based system in xampp (PHP and MySQL) for my company and shared it to our workers through `Local Area Network`.
This system is working perfectly and fulfilling our company requirements and no www or live web hosting is required to our company.
So we are gradually replacing this web based system to old vb application.
**Has PHP and MySQL no issue in any aspect to be used as desktop application? as php and mysql are for web?**

Comment: xampp is just a bundle for php apache and other tools. it should be fine to be used as a server

Comment: Why are PHP and MySQL *for web*? Just because they run on a web server, does not make their application exclusive to building web pages. PHP can be run from CLI, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem for using PHP and MySQL to build desktop applications! WAMP packages are designed for that. You also have tools that compile PHP to EXE to create desktop apps.